# How to force browser to open generated PDF in a new tab? Possible to 'host' generated PDF on Shiny server?

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I have a Shiny app that generates a PDF report given a user's input.

Is it possible to either;

- Force the browser to open the downloaded PDF in a new tab (Firefox does this automatically, but for most browsers the file is only downloaded, and *possibly lost forever in a download-folder so densely populated it becomes a spacetime singularity*), **or**
- 'Hosting' the generated PDF on the server, such that the browser opens the PDF in a new tab as if it was a regular link.

My implementation works like this:

app.R:

```r
# load required libraries
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(htmltools)

# some data
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3), rep("D",3)), 
                 value=rnorm(12))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # let user select a group
  selectInput(inputId = 'group', label = "Pick a Group", choices = unique(dt$group)),
  
  # some customized 'download'-link
  HTML('
    <a id="downloadReport" class="shiny-download-link some-css" href="" target="_blank" download>
      Generate Report
    </a>
  ')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # <--- GENERATE R-MARKDOWN PDF REPORT --->
  
  # define file name  
  file_name <- eventReactive(input$group,{
    paste0("Group-",input$group, ".pdf")
  })
  
  # render custom report
  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() file_name(),
    content = function(file) {
      
    # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
    params <- list(group = input$group)
    
    # path to *.Rmd report  
    src <- normalizePath('dummy-report.Rmd')
      
    # temporarily switch to the temp dir
    owd <- setwd(tempdir())
    on.exit(setwd(owd))
    
    file.copy(src, 'dummy-report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
    out <- render('dummy-report.Rmd', pdf_document())
    file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

dummy-report.Rmd:

````r
---
title: "Awesome Dummy PDF Report"
output: pdf_document
---

# Table with Selected Data

```{r, load_data}

# query relevant data
dt <- dt[which(dt$group == params$group),]

# output table
dt
````

Appreciate any suggestions/help.

Thank you.

Cheers, Christian

Comment: Thanks, I thought so as well. But if the generated PDF was hosted somewhere (e.g. as a temporary file/location), it would be possible to open that location in another tab via 'target="_blank"' as usual, no? Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I had the same problem. In the end, the PDF is now simply displayed inside a modalDialog with the iFrame tag. Maybe also an option for you.

Comment: @Wati interesting. So I suppose this is something like 'hosting' the PDF on shiny server rather than downloading it. Do you have an example somewhere on how to accomplish this in Shiny? I recognized when I put a PDF file inside the 'www'-folder and I put a simple target="_blank" <a>-tag in the UI, across all browsers Chrome, Firefox, Edge, it opens seamlessly inside a new tab. Maybe the same should be possible to achieve with some tweaking? hm